# OpenRefine JSON Templating skip null values

Tags: openrefine

I want to use templating to export my cleaned Data from OpenRefine to JSON. It’s working, but I have a lot of empty cells resulting in something like:

```
"countries" : ["cuba","mexico","puerto rico","united states",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]
```

How can I skip those `null` values?
I’m using the following as my row template code:

```
"countries" : [{{jsonize(cells["country1"].value)}},{{jsonize(cells["country2"].value)}}]
```

and so on.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test if the cell is empty or not before outputting the value. For example

```
"countries" : [{{forNonBlank(cells["country1"],c,jsonize(c.value),"")}},{{forNonBlank(cells["country2"],c,jsonize(c.value),"")}}]
```

If you have lots of 'country' columns you could consider iterating through the columns looking for non-blank values using the Recipes at https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Recipes#7-columns - which maybe more efficient depending on how many columns you are working with

Comment: Thanks! Using `forNonBlank` leaves `"countries" : ["argentina","mexico",,,,,,,,,,,]` so I will look into iterating over the columns.

Comment: Ah - you could also try bringing the comma separator into the conditional - something like:

`"countries" : [{{forNonBlank(cells["country1"],c,jsonize(c.value)+",","")}}{{forNonBlank(cells["country2"],c,jsonize(c.value),"")}}]`

Comment: Thanks, that’s it!